# Spring security XML configuration not protecting URLs

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have gone through a lot of questions similar to this but I couldn't find any solution.

I am using Spring-3.0.5RELEASE and Spring-security-3.1.2RELEASE.
Actually I am adding spring security to already exixsting application.
There are no errors in creating bean or filters but the urls are not protected.

spring-security.xml looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

<!--  <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" /> -->

 <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />

 <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin"
access="hasRole('Admin')" />

 <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard" access="hasRole('Admin')
or hasRole('User')" />

<security:intercept-url pattern="/setup" access="hasRole('User')" />

 <!-- access denied page -->
 <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/logout" />

 <security:form-login 
 login-processing-url="/loginAuth"
 login-page="/index" 
 default-target-url="/dashboard" 
 username-parameter="username"
 password-parameter="password"
 authentication-failure-url="/index"/>
 <!-- enable csrf protection -->
<!-- <csrf/> -->
 <http-basic />
 </security:http>


 <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<security:authentication-manager>
 <security:authentication-provider>
 <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
 users-by-username-query=
 "select customerId, passcode from Users where customerId=?"
 authorities-by-username-query=
 "select customerId, roleName from Role where customerId=?" />
 </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

There is a warning here saying: *Referenced bean 'dataSource' not found*. I am not sure whether this may cause the problem.

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/config/sample-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

sample-servlet.xml

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.as.spark" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.as.spark.model.Users</value>
                <value>com.as.spark.model.Role</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <!-- properties -->
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I don't want to shift to java configuration because that requires a higher version of spring.

All the pages /home, /dashboard, /admin are open to all users.
How do I check whether the filter is applied? How to protect the URL?

Comment: Your datasource should be in the root context that way Spring Security can find it.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace too.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried adding dataSource bean in application-context.xml but again the same problem occurs.

Comment: Which problem? Your custom queries are also wrong. The `users-by-username-query` must return 3 columns not 2. The third column is the indication if a user is enabled or not.

Comment: @SumeshTG There are no errors its working completely normal permitting all the urls

Comment: Is customerId and username are same? `roleName` alias this field to `role` then only spring sercurity will consider it as role.